# Storing factory-boy RelatedFactory Object on Parent Factory

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I have two Django models (`Customer` and `CustomerAddress`) that both contain `ForeignKey`s to each other. I am using factory-boy to manage creation of these models, and cannot save a child factory instance onto the parent factory (using relationships defined using the `RelatedFactory` class).

My two models:

```py
class ExampleCustomerAddress(models.Model):
    # Every customer mailing address is assigned to a single Customer,
    # though Customers may have multiple addresses.
    customer = models.ForeignKey('ExampleCustomer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ExampleCustomer(models.Model):
    # Each customer has a single (optional) default billing address:
    default_billto = models.ForeignKey(
        'ExampleCustomerAddress',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='+')
```

I have two factories, one for each model:

```
class ExampleCustomerAddressFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleCustomerAddress

    customer = factory.SubFactory(
        'ExampleCustomerFactory',
        default_billto=None)  # Set to None to prevent recursive address creation.

class ExampleCustomerFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleCustomer

    default_billto = factory.RelatedFactory(ExampleCustomerAddressFactory,
                                            'customer')
```

When creating a `ExampleCustomerFactory`, `default_billto` is *None*, even though a `ExampleCustomerAddress` has been created:

```
In [14]: ec = ExampleCustomerFactory.build()

In [15]: ec.default_billto is None
Out[15]: True
```

(When using `create()`, a new `ExampleCustomerAddress` exists in the database. I am using `build()` here to simplify the example).

Creating an `ExampleCustomerAddress` works as expected, with the `Customer` being automatically created:

```
In [22]: eca = ExampleCustomerAddressFactory.build()

In [23]: eca.customer
Out[23]: <ExampleCustomer: ExampleCustomer object>

In [24]: eca.customer.default_billto is None
Out[24]: True  <-- I was expecting this to be set to an `ExampleCustomerAddress!`.
```

I feel like I am going crazy here, missing something very simple. I get the impression I am encountering this error because of how both models contain `ForeignKeys` to each other.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, a simple rule of thumb: when you're following a `ForeignKey`, *always* prefer a `SubFactory`; `RelatedFactory` is intended to follow a reverse relationship.

Let's take each factory in turn.

### `ExampleCustomerAddressFactory`

When we call this factory without a customer, we'll want to get an address, linked to a customer, and used as the default address for that customer.

However, when we call it with a customer, don't alter it.

The following would work:

```py
class ExampleCustomerAddressFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleCustomerAddress

    # Fill the Customer unless provided
    customer = factory.SubFactory(
        ExampleCustomerFactory,
        # We can't provide ourself there, since we aren't saved to the database yet.
        default_billto=None,
    )

    @factory.post_generation
    def set_customer_billto(obj, create, *args, **kwargs):
        """Set the default billto of the customer to ourselves if empty"""
        if obj.customer.default_billto is None:
            obj.customer.default_billto = obj
            if create:
                obj.customer.save()
```

Here, we'll set the newly created customer's value to "us"; note that this logic could also be moved to `ExampleCustomerAddress.save()`.

### `ExampleCustomerFactory`

For this factory, the rules are simpler: when creating a customer, create a default billing address (unless a value has been provided).

```py
class ExampleCustomerFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleCustomer

    # We can't use a SubFactory here, since that would be evaluated before
    # the Customer has been saved.
    default_billto = factory.RelatedFactory(
        ExampleCustomerAddressFactory,
        'customer',
    )
```

This factory will run as follows:

1. Create the `ExampleCustomer` instance with `default_billto=None`;
2. Call `ExampleCustomerAddressFactory(customer=obj)` with the newly created customer;
3. That factory will create an `ExampleCustomerAddress` with that customer;
4. The post-generation hook in that factory will then detect that the customer has no `default_billto`, and will override it.

#### Notes

- I didn't test this, so some typos or minor bugs could occur;
- It's up to you to decide which factory is declared first, using the target factory's path instead of a direct reference;
- As stated above, the logic to set the default billing address of a customer when it's empty and an address is added to that customer could be moved to your model's `.save()` method.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! This worked perfectly. For some reason, I got hung up adding the post-generation hook onto the `CustomerFactory`. It never occurred to me to place it onto the `CustomerAddressFactory`. One quick edit to your answer: the `@factory.post_declaration` decorator should be `@factory.post_generation`.